# Tomahawk music player window bottom goes off screen

Tags: release-freya

I use Tomahawk music player on Elementary OS Freya.
Following are the issues i'm facing regarding this palyer:

1. Player opens up every time, without a maximize button.
2. Player window bottom part(Part containing play/pause buttons and seekbar) goes off screen.
3. No way to resize the player.

Please can anyone shed some light on this issue.
Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Which version of Tomahawk are you talking about? The one in the Ubuntu's repository or the latest one from the PPA?

Comment: Tomahawk 0.8.4 from tomahawk ppa

Comment: Well that's weird. I just tested it and wasn't able to replicate any of the problems you've described.

Comment: Maybe the issue is with something else, just can't find out what...

Comment: That looks a bit more like a bug report to me... Have you searched launchpad for similar reports?

Answer (score 1):

Problem got solved. Tomahawk player bottom part now appears normally within screen and also with the maximize button.
The problem got fixed with the recent package update, so i think it might have been a tomahawk issue.